# The zeros of infinite product are not zeros of resulting function.

Tags: convergence-divergence, roots, products

If we consider the product:
$$\prod_{i \ge 1}(1-a_ix^i)=P_n(x)$$
where $P_n(x)$ is polynomial with $n$ roots. It is obvious that the zeros of product are not zeros of polynomial because they are infinite while zero count of right side is $n$. 
My explanation is that the zeros is out of radius of convergence. Is this correct conclusion or there is something else?

ADDITION:
In general if we have 
$$\prod_{i \ge 1}(1-a_ix^i)=f(x)$$
is all roots of product is also root of $f(x)$ ? Answer is no. In this case what is the reason of this "inconsistence"?

ADDITION:
One example:
$$\prod_{k >= 1}{(1-a_kx^k)} = 1 - \frac{x}{1-x}$$
$a_1=1$, $a_2=1$, $a_3=2$, $a_4=8$,...

Comment: Where are you getting that that product is equal to a polynomial?

Comment: If we assume that we have infinite product which equals to some polynominal or to any function in general.

Comment: Formally, if $P_n(0) = 1$, you can choose $a_i$ recursively so that the $x^i$ coefficient of expansion of the left side (which is a polynomial in $a_1, \ldots, a_i$) is the $x^i$ coefficient of the right side.  But I don't know if this infinite product will converge anywhere other than $0$.

Comment: An infinite product may or may not converge.  Just as in the case of infinite series, when trying to assign a "value" to a divergent case, we get contradictions.

Comment: Hint: consider critical value against absolute value: -1/2 + 1/2 against 1 x 1

Answer (score 2):

I can think of some cases that work.  Since
$$ \prod_{j=0}^\infty \left(1 + z^{2^j}\right) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n = \frac{1}{1-z}$$
if $N$ is not a power of $2$ we have
$$ P(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} z^n = \frac{1-z^N}{1-z} = \prod_{k=1}^\infty (1 + a_k z^k)$$
where $$\eqalign{a_{2^j} &= 1\cr a_N &= -1\cr a_k &= 0\ \text{otherwise}}$$
all converging in the open unit disk.  Indeed, the roots of $1 + z^{2^j}$ are not roots of $P(z)$.

Comment: Good example. And in this case not sure if I understand what is the reason of this inconsystency?

Comment: There is no inconsistency.  There is no reason for the roots of the factors of the left side outside the region of convergence to be roots of the right side.